# Handling MySQL JSON field default values

Tags: mysql, alter

I need to come up with an SQL that can `ALTER` a JSON field.

1. A JSON field was configured with default value of `{}`
2. But I'm getting `_utf8mb4'{}'` back when querying the DDL
3. I was expecting the default value to be `{}`.
4. Any idea where is `_utf8mb4` documented and how do I handle it correctly?

UPDATE:

1. Version is 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

```
ALTER TABLE demo MODIFY COLUMN settings JSON NOT NULL DEFAULT ('{}');
SHOW CREATE TABLE demo;
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  ...
  `settings` json NOT NULL DEFAULT (_utf8mb4'{}'),
  ...  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Show how you are "querying the DDL"?  If you insert a row without specifying the column, is it set to {}?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-literal.html

Comment: *A JSON field was configured with default value of `{}`* ?? How do you do this? BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON columns can't have a default value on all MySQL versions.

Comment: Can you please run the query `SELECT VERSION();` and report the result?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html says:

> MySQL handles strings used in JSON context using the utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_bin collation. Strings in other character sets are converted to utf8mb4 as necessary.

The syntax you see, `_utf8mb4'{}'` is just a string literal with a character set introducer.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html says:

> A character string literal may have an optional character set introducer and COLLATE clause, to designate it as a string that uses a particular character set and collation:
>
> ```
> [_charset_name]'string' [COLLATE collation_name]
> ```

Since JSON must use utf8mb4, I am guessing it is adding the introducer to the default expression to ensure that the string is encoded with the proper character set, just in case someone tries to insert into the table from a session configured with a different session character set.

The same thing happens if you add other text columns:

```
mysql> alter table demo add column t text default ('abc');

mysql> show create table demo\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: demo
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `settings` json NOT NULL DEFAULT (_utf8mb4'{}'),
  `t` text DEFAULT (_utf8mb4'abc')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```